# Int arrays in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, integer

So I have this:

```
int a[4] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
```

And then I want to make a new int array:

```
int b[4];
```

What is the easiest way to make b[] = a[]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
memcpy(b, a, sizeof(int) * 4);
```